# How do I order vectors from sentence embeddings and give them out with their respective input?

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, embedding, sentence-similarity

I managed to generate vectors for every sentence in my two corpora and calculate the Cosine Similarity between every possible pair (dot product):

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")

embeddings1 = ["I'd like an apple juice",
                                "An apple a day keeps the doctor away",
                                 "Eat apple every day",
                                 "We buy apples every week",
                                 "We use machine learning for text classification",
                                 "Text classification is subfield of machine learning"]
embeddings1 = embed(embeddings1)

embeddings2 = ["I'd like an orange juice",
                                "An orange a day keeps the doctor away",
                                 "Eat orange every day",
                                 "We buy orange every week",
                                 "We use machine learning for document classification",
                                 "Text classification is some subfield of machine learning"]
embeddings2 = embed(embeddings2)

print(cosine_similarity(embeddings1, embeddings2))

array([[ 0.7882168 ,  0.3366559 ,  0.22973989,  0.15428472, -0.10180502,
                                                         -0.04344492],
       [ 0.256085  ,  0.7713026 ,  0.32120776,  0.17834462, -0.10769081,
                                                         -0.09398925],
       [ 0.23850328,  0.446203  ,  0.62606746,  0.25242645, -0.03946173,
                                                         -0.00908459],
       [ 0.24337521,  0.35571027,  0.32963073,  0.6373588 ,  0.08571904,
                                                         -0.01240187],
       [-0.07001016, -0.12002315, -0.02002328,  0.09045915,  0.9141338 ,
                                                          0.8373743 ],
       [-0.04525191, -0.09421931, -0.00631144, -0.00199519,  0.75919366,
                                                          0.9686416 ]]
```

In order to have a meaningful output I would need to order them, then return them with the respective input sentences. Does anyone have an idea how doing that? I did not find any tutorial for that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed strings instead of a lsit of strings. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You might use, `np.argsort(...)` for sorting,

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")

seq1 = ["I'd like an apple juice",
                                "An apple a day keeps the doctor away",
                                 "Eat apple every day",
                                 "We buy apples every week",
                                 "We use machine learning for text classification",
                                 "Text classification is subfield of machine learning"]
embeddings1 = embed(seq1)

seq2 = ["I'd like an orange juice",
                                "An orange a day keeps the doctor away",
                                 "Eat orange every day",
                                 "We buy orange every week",
                                 "We use machine learning for document classification",
                                 "Text classification is some subfield of machine learning"]
embeddings2 = embed(seq2)

a = cosine_similarity(embeddings1, embeddings2)
```

---

```
def get_pairs(a, b):

 a = np.array(a)
 b = np.array(b)

 c = np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b))
 c = c.T.reshape(len(a), -1, 2)

 return c
```

---

```
pairs = get_pairs(seq1, seq2)

sorted_idx = np.argsort(a, axis=0)[..., None]

sorted_pairs = pairs[sorted_idx]


print(pairs[0, 0])
print(pairs[0, 1])
print(pairs[0, 2])
```

---

```
["I'd like an apple juice" "I'd like an orange juice"]
["I'd like an apple juice" 'An orange a day keeps the doctor away']
["I'd like an apple juice" 'Eat orange every day']
```

Comment: Okay, and how would you write it more generally so that I could do it for input of 500 rows comparing with 5,000 rows plus also returning the vectors?

Comment: It does not work. I put in "I'd like an apple juice" in the second corpus' last entry and your code simply returns the first three entries without classification.

Comment: My thought would be to perform the embedding after taking out one sentence with a for loop but then it says it is the wrong input.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that your problem doesn't come from this solution. Could you mention the error you have got?

Comment: Sure, your code does not have an error but it just returns the corpus with performing classification. If I do the embeddings with a for loop I get this message: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  input must be a vector, got shape: []
  [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/StringSplit}}]] [Op:__inference_restored_function_body_5285]

Function call stack:
restored_function_body

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand how loops could make a difference, I guess it's might be a dimension or a data type issue. Could you show me for loop code? , I might try to deduce what's going wrong.

Comment: def embed(x):
    for i in x:
        embed(i)
        return i

embed(embeddings1) I also have another pipeline where I would like to integrate the results of the cosine similarities. They must be identifiable though

Comment: Are you trying to define a recursive function, `def embed(x):` ?, if so, you should avoid overloaded function, (i.e. `embed(...)`, is also a member function for `tensorflow_hub` module.